# Display value of datetime in textboxfor at edit time

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I am using HTML5 `type = "date"` and it's working fine. 
But when there is `type="datetime-local"`, at the time of editing field it's not displaying using `TextBoxFor()` in MVC4

This one is working,

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.date, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control",@placeholder = "DateTime", @type = "date" })
```

in `texbox = "2/15/2015"`

but

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.datetime, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "OpeningDoor", @type = "datetime-local" })
```

not displaying data when there is value in "datetime".

```
textbox = "mm/dd/yyyy _:_:_" instead of "1/15/2015 01:40:00 PM"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format string needs to be `"{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss}"` or you can simply use `"{0:s}"`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.datetime, "{0:s}", new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "OpeningDoor", type = "datetime-local" })
```

Side note: `type="date"` and `type="datetime-local"` are only supported in Chrome (a normal textbox will be generated in FireFox and IE) so you should consider using a jquery plugin. Refer [browser comparison](https://html5test.com/compare/browser/chrome-44/firefox-40/ie-11.html).